# Why portrait content displayed inside the landscape orientation?

Tags: ios, objective-c

For a view controller, I am using the following code to restrict the orientation to landscape.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   // Return YES for supported orientations
   return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

However, the display result is not correct

It shows the portrait content inside the landscape window.

what will be the possible cause?

Comment: have to set frames for subviews according to landscape or use AutoLayouts http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: Hi, are you doing it for a specific View or you want your whole application to be in landscape Mode.

Answer (score 0):

remove the unwanted orientation from your info.plist or just go through Autolayout in ios